# Leave only the elements that are not repeated in a given list IN SCHEME

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, lisp

So I'm trying to solve this question with SCHEME so that if a list (a b a a a c c ) has given the answer will be (a b).
I've written an answer as follows:

*ignore the parentheses*

```scm
(define (repelem x)
  (cond ((null? (car x)) 
         '())
        ((/= (car x) (cdr x)) 
         (cons (car x) repelem (cdr x))))))
```

But it doesn't work for some reason. I thought of adding a variable that would count the instances of the element then print it only if the instances are 0. However, I couldn't figure any way to write it down with SCHEME.

Please I need help if anyone knows how such a problem can be solved.

Comment: It's not a direct duplicate since then `c` would have been represented in the result but isn't since every places where there are `c`'s it's next to another `c`. C?

Comment: I believe the code doesn't even work. Look at the last `cons` call. It has 3 parameters.